# What is the cultural equivalent of anachronism?

Tags: single-word-requests

An anachronism is something that is out of place in time. What word do you use if it's something that is out of place in culture? For example a movie may use a kissing scene to depict intimacy even though the culture in which the plot is set does not have this practice.

Comment: anaculturalism?

Comment: for something more general, but is an actual word: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anatopism

Comment: Actually some do use it for cultural matters:
"**1912: Augustus Hopkins Strong, Miscellanies**
*There is no anachronism in putting them together; it is a sort of anatopism rather; the painter has placed within our view two scenes which no mortal eye could have witnessed at the same time.*

**1995: Tony Killick, The Flexible Economy: Causes and Consequences of the Adaptability of National Economies**
*Much of the literature on the 'Japanese Miracle' (as well as on that vast anatopism, the transfer of Japanese recipes to Western countries) expatiates on ..."*

Comment: Also general, but I'd call it incongruous.

Comment: I do not think there is a word for cultural inconsistency.

Comment: I’d call that ***foreign***

Comment: @V0ight, you should write up an answer for *anaculturism* and *anatopism*. Both are excellent (and useful) words!

Comment: @Silenus ~ anaculturalism is just a made-up word, but ok I'll write an answer :)

Comment: @V0ight, well you can mention that it doesn't have much use but that it is used in at least one place (http://creativityhacker.ca/2014/10/13/the-amazing-adventures-of-toby-the-trilby-by-angela-castillo/).

Comment: @Silenus ~ thank you, Google books had some book results which surprised me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**anatopism** is the spatial equivalent of anachronism, but it can and has been used in cultural contexts.

[wiktionary:](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/anatopism)

> *(rare) A thing that is out of its proper place; the geographic counterpart to anachronism.*

[American Architecture Studies](https://books.google.com/books?id=LqEyAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA86&dq=%22anatopism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjAiOepue_NAhWm64MKHW92AxsQ6AEIOTAF#v=onepage&q=%22anatopism%22&f=false)

> *The saying that ours is not a cathedral-building age is so obviously true, and so familiar, that the proposal to erect in New York the most important religious monument on this side of the Atlantic strikes many, and perhaps most, cultivated persons with a sense of incongruity. It is so especially true that this is not a cathedral-building country that an American cathedral seems a violation of the unities in place not less than in time--an **anatopism** as well as an anachronism.*

[Miscellanies: Volume II -- Chiefly Theological](https://books.google.com/books?id=lQ02AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA143&dq=%22anatopism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlyvynuO_NAhVJ1oMKHcxzA4AQ6AEIKzAD#v=onepage&q=%22anatopism%22&f=false)

> *There is no anachronism in putting them together; it is a sort of **anatopism** rather; the painter has placed within our view two scenes which no mortal eye could have witnessed at the same time.*

[The Art of Music: Volume 4](https://books.google.com/books?id=_VApAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA413&dq=%22anatopism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlyvynuO_NAhVJ1oMKHcxzA4AQ6AEINjAF#v=onepage&q=%22anatopism%22&f=false)

> *To place the delicate and fragile spirit of a Watteau or a Gretry in the midst of the hurly-burly of American life would seem a sorry anachronism, as well as **anatopism**, on the part of the Providence which rules over the destinies of art.*

[The Spectatorship of Suffering](https://books.google.com/books?id=TOnoktc9roQC&printsec=frontcover&dq=the+spectatorship+of+suffering&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiJoYCGve_NAhUDTSYKHfieDkQQ6AEIHDAA#v=onepage&q=anatopism&f=false)

> ***Anatopism*** renders places such as Bali equivalents of other places, such as Kenya, on the basis of a hitherto irrelevant feature shared by the two: their lack of safety. The safe spectators no longer register the facts of a distant world but are faced with the threat of experiencing such suffering themselves.

[Notes on the Chiriquí Lagoon District and Adjacent Regions of Panama](https://books.google.com/books?id=vhxmAAAAMAAJ&q=%22anatopism%22&dq=%22anatopism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjlsOrtt-_NAhXr5oMKHaQ1BuI4ChDoAQgpMAM)

> *The lore of Christianity is so strongly associated with other climes that it appears as something of an **anatopism** in the rainforest; lambs, for example, don't do well here.*

[The Flexible Economy: Causes and Consequences of the Adaptability of National Economies](https://books.google.com/books?id=RlaKAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&dq=%22anatopism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj06p74te_NAhWo5IMKHTNIB4A4ChDoAQgtMAM#v=onepage&q=%22anatopism%22&f=false)

> *Much of the literature on the 'Japanese Miracle' (as well as on that vast **anatopism**, the transfer of Japanese recipes to Western countries) expatiates on the actions of businesses and government in tandem.*

[Narratives of failure and impossibility: Dismantling silenced trauma in postdictatorial Argentina](https://books.google.com/books?id=eTQeAQAAMAAJ&q=%22anatopism%22&dq=%22anatopism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiX4J6Ft-_NAhUH4oMKHT8CBJEQ6AEIODAG)

> *Osvaldo Soriano's 1986 novel, written from exile, which paradoxically became his first bestseller in Argentina, removes Malvinas from Argentina through an **anatopism** that takes the novel's action to a fictional African country.*

---

'**anaculturalism**' is more specific, but rarely used, apparently created by Roland Greene in 1999.

[Abrasive dream: Latino writers and the ethnic paradigm](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22anaculturalism%22&biw=1202&bih=686&source=lnt&tbs=cdr%3A1%2Ccd_min%3A1%2F1%2F1500%2Ccd_max%3A12%2F31%2F2016&tbm=bks)

> *"**Anaculturalism**," defined by Greene as a "virtual crossing of cultures"*

[Unrequited Conquests: Love and Empire in the Colonial Americas](https://books.google.com/books?id=CafqmVVGqQUC&pg=PA14&lpg=PA14&dq=%22anaculturalism%22&source=bl&ots=Cca-2brbWl&sig=obzyb5cfiLO9z_AyKzCNw4mN5rA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6w_SLu-_NAhXo8YMKHZa8CdQQ6AEIKjAC#v=onepage&q=%22anaculturalism%22&f=false)

> *Therefore, **anaculturalism** or the virtual crossing of cultures, while it originates as a response to unrequitedness, becomes a spur to that condition--an unrealizable ideal for a class of Europeans who will never again feel entirely at home in the newly-expanded world.*

---

or **anaculturism** (1989), thanks to user @Silenus in the comments

[Science Fiction & Fantasy Book Review Annual](https://books.google.com/books?id=_VwqAQAAIAAJ&q=%22anaculturism%22&dq=%22anaculturism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-9ezUvu_NAhXB4CYKHQRnDxcQ6AEIHDAA)

> *His trolls and demons have the temperament and speech patterns of office workers. Much of the dialogue sounds like bad office memos ("deem expedient," "viable option"), with token words like "whoreson" thrown in. Mills is guilty, to coin a bastardized term, of "**anaculturism**" (rather than "anachronism").*

[The Journal of Egyptian Archaeology: Volume 90](https://books.google.com/books?id=V2IPAQAAMAAJ&q=%22anaculturism%22&dq=%22anaculturism%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi-9ezUvu_NAhXB4CYKHQRnDxcQ6AEIIDAB)

> *...which potentially makes the argument vulnerable to charges of anachronism and **anaculturism**.*

[creativityhacker.ca -- Blog by Jefferson Smith](http://creativityhacker.ca/2014/10/13/the-amazing-adventures-of-toby-the-trilby-by-angela-castillo/)

> ***Anaculturism***: When an author uses a word that is inconsistent with the culture of his story.

Comment: I'd pick **anaculturism** over **anatopism** due to the specific reference to culture despite the later being more lexically mature

Answer (score 0):

The words like "allochronism" may be tried as enumerated in the link herein below:
http://definithing.com/allochronism/

Asynchrony / ASYNCHRONISM may be the other potentially helpful words in the given context.